# Enable Task Tags in cucumber .feature files

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

I have an Eclipse project that I'm testing with Cucumber. I want to add a TODO task in the .feature file, so it shows up in Eclipse's Tasks view.

Is this possible and if so, how to enable these tags?

```
...
Given some condition
# TODO add And for additional setup <-- Show up in tasks view?!
Then check some things.
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TODO: is work with Only language not with feature file

Comment: I tried this already, but I have no luck with it (hence the question). Could you maybe check you configuration for any specific setups?

Comment: @Timo #TODO is work with language like .rb, I have googled it will not work with .feature feature